# How to have two column on my index page?

Tags: columns

I want two full columns after the header and main menu bar on my index page. Seems simple, but googling and prowling the wordpress.org site hasn't gotten me anywhere. Short explanation + a link to relevant section of TFM to R would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you post the name (and download link) of your theme? does your theme use 'post_class()' in the post div?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the theme you are using. The index.php file in your theme applies to your home page. So if you change the HTML structure in there to be 3 columns, your home page should be 3 columns.

Be careful though because index.php will also apply in some cases beyond the home page. Take a look at the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) for the order of precedence theme files are matched on for any given request.

Comment: Its best you create a home.php template file so that only your homepage is affected. If you do this on the index.php then anything without a template file will load it. I am just adding on to what Dave said. Read over the Hierarchy it makes a whole lot of sense